# 変数の内容によって特定の変数の型を決定する方法

Tags: typescript

TypeScriptにおいて，ある文字列変数の内容によって特定の変数の型（`test`とします）を自動的に設定されるようにしたいです。
具体的な例を挙げると，

```js
const type = "basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >";
```

のとき，変数 `test` の型は `string`

```js
const type = "unsigned int";
```

や

```js
const type = "float";
```

などのときは変数 `test` の型は `number` と自動的に設定されるような処理を知りたいです。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/hgfoe1fbw5kb9l と同じ質問でしょうか？

Comment: 動的に変数の型を決定したい理由は何でしょうか？一般的に動的に変数の型を変更できるように実装するのは言語特性上好ましくないと思われます。動的に変数を扱わないければいけない時点で詳細設計のどこかが良くない可能性があります。

Comment: @merino はい。teratailサーバーがあまりにもレスポンスに時間を要し、評判もあまり良くはないので退会させていただきました。

Comment: @keitaro_so 実際に質問のような処理は最初の時（importされた時）のみでしか行われない予定というか確定なので、ライブラリ使用者目線からは実質的には静的な型と設定されます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

条件付きタイプ（[`Conditional Types`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html)）を使用する例です。変数 `spec` に依存して変数 `test` の型が決まります。

```js
type StringSpec = "basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >"
type NumberSpec = "unsigned int" | "float"
type Spec = StringSpec | NumberSpec
type TypeBySpec<T extends Spec> =
    T extends StringSpec ? string
    : T extends NumberSpec ? number
    : never

const spec: Spec = "unsigned int"
let test: TypeBySpec<typeof spec>  // test は number型
```

`spec` が実行時に計算される場合は、`test` の型も実行時にしか定まらないので、`string | number` になります。

```
// 実行時に値が決まる場合
const spec: Spec = ((new Date().getSeconds()) >= 30)
    ? "basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >"
    : "unsigned int"

let test: TypeBySpec<typeof spec>  // test は「string | number」型
```